# Moq.MockVerificationException not public xUnit Assert.Throws

Tags: moq, xunit.net

I am testing a method which will call another method if certain parameters are certain values and not if they are other.

I was using Moq's `Verify` to test this.  However when I use the xUnit to see if the method is not called when sending parameters with data which should not make the method call the 2nd method.

Problem is that I cannot do

```
mockObject.Verify();
Assert.Throws<Moq.MockVerificationException>(()=>mockObject.Method());
```

I changed from MSTest to xUnit because the support for throws was built in and I had to have the `ExpectedException` attribute decorating my test method before.

I tried to cast the Moq non-public exception to the public parent `Moq.MoqException` but that will throw an error.

so I think I may have to do:

```
try {moqObj.Verify();}
catch(Moq.Exception mve)
{
    Assert.SomethingIsException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you're just trying to verify whether certain methods are called or not? If so, try this:

```
var theThing = new Mock<IThing> ();

theThing.Verify (x => x.DoSomething ("a"), Times.Never);
theThing.Verify (x => x.DoSomething ("b"), Times.Once);
```

If you need to invoke another method after the first method is called, you could use a callback:

```
theThing.Setup (x => x.DoSomething ("a")).Callback (() => {});
```